# Will Android Studio work in laptop with 1366 x 768 resolution?

Tags: resolution, laptop-display, android-studio

I am planning to buy a laptop to start Android Programming. Android Studio requires 1200 x 800 resolution. Most of the laptops in my budget have 1366 x 768 resolution? Will Android Studio work in this resolution or won't even start? What other issues I may face?

Thanks,

Comment: Your question is already answered [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29159148/do-android-studio-run-on-1366-by-768-pixel-laptop

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for sure. Mine have got that resolution. It's a bit small, but will work. Many of today laptops ships with this resolution

Comment: Why you downvote me, Saurabh? Any reason? Competence?

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it will work.
Most of the laptops come with 16:9 aspect ratio, and 1366x768 is a standard resolution.